# wordpress search result page

Tags: wordpress, search

I have a problem with my search page result. I already create search theme.
when I search word 'موفقیت' which it is already in my data base it return all result and works fine but I just want to search in special custom post type not all of post and pages.how can I fix this problem

here is my code

```
    <?php 
 get_header(); ?>
<div class="title-pack col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <span class="line visible-sm-block"></span>
        <span class="visible-sm-block tittle-style">نتایج جستجوی شما</span>
    </div>
<div id="search-results" class="wrapper" role="search">


<!-- COUNT RESULTS -->
<div class="results">
    <?php
    /* Search Count */
    $allsearch = &new WP_Query("s=$s&showposts=-1"); 
    $key = wp_specialchars($s, 1);
    $count = $allsearch->post_count; 
    _e('');
    _e('"<span class="search-terms">');
    echo $key;
    _e('</span>"'); 
    echo $count . ' مورد یافت شد';
    wp_reset_query(); ?>

</div>
<!-- / COUNT RESULTS -->

<?php if ($allsearch->have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while ($allsearch->have_posts()) : $allsearch->the_post(); ?>

<!-- LIST RESULTS -->
<section>   
    <h3>
        <li>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to 
        <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a> - 
        <span class="search-time"><?php the_time('F, j, Y') ?></span>
        </li>
    </h3>
</section>
<!-- / LIST RESULTS -->

<?php endwhile; else: ?>

<!-- 404 SEARCH -->
<div class="404-search">
<?php _e("Oops... We couldn't find what you were searching for. Please try again"); ?>
</div>
<!-- / 404 SEARCH -->

<?php endif; ?>

     </div>


 <div style="clear:both;"></div>            
 <?php get_footer(); ?> 


     <div style="clear:both;"></div>            
     <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

any idea would be appropriated.

Comment: If you want to filter by post type, add [`post_type`](https://codex.wordpress.org/wp_query#Type_Parameters) to your query.

Comment: I added ` $allsearch = &new WP_Query('s=$s&showposts=-1', 'post_type' => 'book'); ` but it doesn'tt work. :(

Comment: of course it doesn't work. either you use the array syntax or the query synax for the arguments. mixing them doesn't work.

Comment: ok now how can I fix it?

Comment: @GeraldSchneiderI  I got what you said , I fix it, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$search_query['post_status'] = 'publish';
$search_query['post_type'] = 'book'; //your custom post type
// Custom query.
$search = new WP_Query($search_query);

// Check that we have query results.
if ( $search->have_posts() ) {

    // Start looping over the query results.
    while ( $search->have_posts() ) {

        $search->the_post();

        // Contents of the queried post results go here.

    }

}

// Restore original post data.
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: try by adding `$search_query[posts_per_page] = '-1';` just before `$search = new WP_Query($search_query);`

Comment: I try to change the way of my coding and it work perfectly but I want to just search for special custom post type 'book'. do you know how can I fix it?

Comment: Yes, I have updated my code. Use have to pass `post_type` in `WP_Query` args.

Comment: are you sure your post_type slug is `book`?

Comment: what was the issue?

Comment: as  Gerald Schneider said I try to use two way with each other and it doesn't work.